# HTML - fitting an image to a table cell by height

Tags: php, html

OK guys, I need some help...

I have a table cell which I need to fill with an image I get from an url. The image width/height ratio is different than the one of the table cell - the image is longer than the cell. I need to fit it in with 100% height, and trim the left and right ends so it fits by width.

I am new to the website so I can't post pics of examples, but I hope I made myself clear as to what is the problem...

Any help would be highly appreciated...

Comment: You will need to load the image with PHP, then resize it, save it if you wish to use it again, then display it to the browser.

Comment: Resizing isn't a problem, but when I shrink the width of the image - it gets blurry, or stretched out... I need to crop it somehow, or a way to show a part of the image...

Comment: If you're just changing the width and height in the `<img>` tag then you'll see a blurry image. You need to use the GD library or Imagemagick (or similar) to actually resize it.

Comment: Do you have an example I can use?

Comment: There are lots of tutorials on Google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to set it as a background image for the table cell, it will get cropped visually automatically.

If you want to resize that background image so that it completely covers the table cell, while maintaining its aspect ration, you can use the css3 property (limited browser support, IE...):

```
background-size: cover;
```

The complete code:

```
background: url(/url/to/image) no-repeat center center;
background-size: cover;     // just for modern browsers
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried that, but it shows the upper left corner of the pic. How can I center the background image?